# Compute all homology groups of all compact surfaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, compactness, homology-cohomology

The problem is in the title. I'm not sure how to go about this. I think it's going to turn into a bunch of cases. How do I even know what all of the compact surfaces are?

Comment: There are two families of compact surfaces: orientable and non-orientable. So really only two cases.

Comment: We know that in either case they are 2-dimensional manifolds, so we only need to compute $H_0X$, $H_1X$ and $H_2X$. Assume the compact surface $X$ is connected. This gives $H_0X$. Which of the two cases (orientable or non-orientable) decides $H_2X$. So really you're left with calculating $H_1X$, and this is essentially given to you when you compare with the classification theorems for surfaces.

Comment: Why can you assume that $X$ is connected?

Comment: Assume its not. It's compact so there has a finite number of connected components. Count them. This gives you $H_0X$. Restricting to each component you then calculate $H_*X_i$ of each component $X_i$ and use the additivity of homology to get $H_*X$.